# Herkunft einen an der Waffel haben?

Tags: idiom

Diese Redewendung heisst wohl bescheuert sein.
Aber woher kommt es? Kann mir nichts darunter vorstellen.

Man denkt da an das [Gebäck Waffe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffel)l vielleicht.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Für Dinge, die den Menschen wichtig sind, gibt es häufig viele Synonyme. Darunter fällt das Geld (Knete, Kohle, Kies, ...), die Sexualorgane (Beispiele spare ich mir ;) ) oder auch der Kopf (Birne, Hirse, Omme, Rübe, Dez, ...).

"Waffel" ist ein Synonym für den Mund. Laut dem  [Deutschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW01036#XGW01036) der Gebrüder Grimm ist "Waffel"

> ein in ober- und mitteldeutschen mundarten und in der älteren litteratur verbreitetes wort, das wol zunächst auf das verbum waffeln (s. d.) zurückgeht, das seinerseits eine weiterbildung von dem onomatopoetischen waffen ist.

und steht unter anderem für

> groszer mund mit herabhängenden lippen

Zum [Verb "waffeln"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW01054#XGW01054) wiederum heißt es dort unter anderem

> undeutlich und schnell reden, die worte durch einander werfen

oder

> am verbreitetsten ist die bedeutung schwätzen, in den tag hinein reden

Die [GfdS](https://gfds.de/bedeutung-von-einen-an-der-waffel-haben/) schließt daraus, dass "einen an der Waffel haben" jemanden beschreiben soll, der "waffelt", also der die Worte durcheinanderschmeißt und Unsinn daherredet. Der Begriff "Waffel" hat sich demnach gewissermaßen vom Mund auf den ganzen Kopf ausgedeht. Wer "einen an der Waffel" hat, hat "einen (Schaden) am Kopf".

Das Gebäck [Waffel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffel) hat hingegen hiermit nichts zu tun.

Comment: Ich kenne die *Waffel* tatsächlich nur als Ausdruck für den Kopf - Der Mund ist mir nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Interessanterweise ist auch im Englischen "to waffle" bekannt für *schwätzen*. (Zuletzt gehört aus dem Mund von Australiern.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Es gibt auch das Substantiv "waffle" für "leeres Geschwätz", meines Wissens vor allem im britischen Englisch. Das wurde in der verlinkten Erklärung der GfdS auch kurz erwähnt.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck super, danke! verstehe aber noch den Part noch nicht: "das seinerseits eine weiterbildung von dem onomatopoetischen waffen ist."

Comment: @J.Doe Die Gebrüder Grimm kamen damals zu dem Ergebnis, dass das Substantiv "Waffel" vom Verb "waffeln" abgeleitet wurde, das seinerseits vom onomatopoetischen (lautmalerischen) "waffen" stamme.