# Meaning of Idiomatic Expression: "einen an der Waffel haben"

Tags: translation, idiom

I have just seen in the youtube comments section of a video I was looking at:

> "Du hast einen an der Waffel, das ist alles!"

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Also see (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46858/herkunft-einen-an-der-waffel-haben

Answer (score 5):

"Waffel" is a pastry, but it was also an old word for mouth or head that isn't used any more except in some idioms.

The english word "to waffle" (to ramble, to prate) is related.

"Du hast einen an der Waffel" means there's something wrong with your head, you're a lunatic. It's not really clear what "einen" refers to in this idiom, presumably some kind of damage.

"Du kriegst gleich einen auf die Waffel" would mean you're on the verge of getting hit on the head or the mouth.

> "Du hast einen an der Waffel, das ist alles!"

means "You're a lunatic, that is the end of it."

Goes without saying that it is rude to the max, even for a Youtube comment.

Comment: Haha, thanks HalvarF for the explanation. I won't be repeating this to Germans!

Comment: It's not really a strong expression, so there's no harm in saying this jokingly to Germans. They probably laught about it and will be impressed that you know this obscure phrase

Comment: Ok. Thank you infinitezero.

Comment: Like most insults, you can say it jokingly to people who know you well. Using it on the internet towards people you don't know is a different thing though imo.

Comment: *"Du kriegst gleich einen auf die Waffel"*? Where, when, is that reliable and original or predating the idiom? Da habe ich so meine Zwaffel.

Answer (score 4):

*Einen an der Waffel haben*  is a sloppy phrase denoting intellectual deficiencies in the same category as:

- nicht ganz richtig im Kopf sein
- einen Schlag haben
- einen Sprung in der Schüssel haben
- einen Vogel / eine Meise haben

Additional material found at [Rolf-Bernhard Essig on SWR](https://www.swr.de/wissen/1000-antworten/kultur/1000-antworten-2222.html) or [Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache](https://gfds.de/bedeutung-von-einen-an-der-waffel-haben/). Due to these numerous examples (there seems to be a pressing need to state that meaning) there seems not much benefit of mentioning that *Waffel* refers to mouth, which is considered as outlet from the special brain; but it may assist in remembering the meaning.

Comment: Thank You guidot, much appreciated.

Comment: Your answer would be even better, if you could add on quote from one of the links that explains, that „Waffel“ stands for the mouth / the head in this context...

Comment: In comparison with the remark about *mouth* one can only think of English *waffle*, which is a verb however and as a noun could then only imply *speech*, approximately (cp. for analogy *Mund* und vorgeblich nicht verwandt *(Vor)mund*, *bevormunden*, auch in *Leumund*, zuweilen *Munt*, und daneben *meinen*, Lat. *ment-* "mind", usw. usf.).Demnach dürfte es durchaus erheblich sein dass man "an der" auch als *ander-* verstanden haben wollen könnte. Quasi: Du hast aber eben noch was ganz *anderes gemeint*. Ich find das ziemlich offensichtlich, also wirich kaum der Rede wert. Danke für den Hinweis.